# Do I need to surround a <TableView> with a <StackLayout> in a <ContentPage>

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an application where the developer has a `<ContentPage>` with a `<TableView>` inside. Is this needed / normal practice? I am trying to work out why the developer did this.

The developer added a  element surrounding the `<TableView>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Network">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <TableView>
               ... 
            </TableView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ContentPage can only have a single child element.  It's not uncommon to include some sort of Layout container as the child, so multiple child elements can be added to the page.  However, in cases like this where there is really only a single child it's probably unnecessary.